# embedded software structure for sublevel screens and menus

Tags: c, embedded, structure

I'm new into embedded c programming and I need some advice.

I'm trying to create a menu structure with underneath screens on an embedded system, the OS code and the drawing/menu libraries are ready, but I can't figure out how I'd design this system.

it'll have :

- menus and submenus
- password screens that user can authenticate before entering some menu items
- and the screens beneath them.

I wrote some code that's working and still feels like I'm writing procedural spagetti code. And I'm new to embedded c systems so I don't know if I can use classes or objects inside the code. I'd be grateful if someone shows me the right way to do this. I'm experienced about programming anything else BTW so feel free with the tech talk. ;)

BTW the menu code is structured like this:

```
menu myMenu;
entry* myMenuEntries;
int selection = 0;
myMenuEntries[0] = [entry definer code];
...
myMenu.entries = (entry *) myMenuEntries;
selection = DisplayMenu(myMenu);
switch(selection){
   case 0: exit(); break;
}
```

How can I create an object in embedded c like it's used in `myMenu.entries`?

Comment: This is often a perfect fit for state machines.  The button presses are interpreted/handled in the context of the current state, which is determined by the current menu.  Even better, use state hierarchy (HSM) so that common functionality can be placed in superstates.  The spaghetti code (lots of flags, lots of if/else) tends to disappear when state machines are used.

Comment: I tried designing the states like `CurrentScreenMode=ESCREENMODE_MENU1;` then according to the mode, the process changes, but still I'm not satisfied with it. I'll read about HSM's.

Comment: @Dan + 1 for HSM - much easier to manage, especially when enhancing/upgrading.  Straight code for this quickly becomes unmanageable gunge with logical errors.

Comment: @Dan, Should I design password screens as states, or make them just obstacles before state changes? Do you have any idea about this?

Comment: @Dan, write your comment as an answer and I'll accept that. SM's helped me so much here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would definitely use object oriented C here, like you suspect is possible.  There are lots of references to how to do oop in C on stack overflow. You make classes out of structs and use function pointers as the member functions which can then be overridden if you want polymorphism.

Each screen could have on onEnter(), for example, to initialize stuff when the screen is loaded, and you could have a drawable class that can encompass strings, primitives, images, etc that know how to draw themselves at any x,y coordinate. You could also have a standard screen object which is made up of a list of the objects on the screen, their coordinates, and contents. These could be initialized at compile time, too, in a big table.

(I've done all this on a DSP using C and ASM)

There are also ready made libraries that can do this. I know that micrium has one.  I'm on my phone or I'd Google it and put the link here.

Comment: I have an event driven embedded environment and screen is drawn by a draw event based on current state. Think this layer as a higher level (low level -> OS -> framework -> my layer) environment. this is why I'm confused when coding.